# Immutable Insert alternative

Tags: c#, collections, insert

I'm looking for an immutable alternative for the standard `Collection<T>.Insert(Int32, T)` method.

In my specific case I have a method like this:

```
IEnumerable<int> Foo(IEnumerable<int> parameter, int index)
{
    var copiedParameter = new List<int>(parameter);
    copiedParameter.Insert(index, 42);
    return copiedParameter;
}
```

This obviously is rather exhausting and inefficient. I'd need something like this:

```
IEnumerable<int> Foo(IEnumerable<int> parameter, int index) => parameter.InsertImmutable(index, 42);
```

Of course I could write an extension method like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> InsertImmutable<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection, int index, T value)
{
    var copiedCollection = new List<T>(collection);
    copiedCollection.Insert(index, value);
    return copiedCollection;
}
```

But this obviously doesn't really improve the situation, it just moves the problem to another place.

The only other way of doing this I could think about, is something like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> InsertImmutable<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection, int index, T value)
{
    var i = 0;
    foreach (var item in collection)
    {
        if (i == index)
            yield return value;
        yield return item;

        i++;
    }
}
```

However, this iterates the `IEnumerable` which once again can decrease the efficiency.

Is there a better, lazy and immutable way to do this?

Comment: You cannot avoid copying I'm afraid if you require immutability, since content owned by initial instance should be copied to another memory area. The only things you can control somewhat are efficiency of copying process and deferring the execution of inserts to the moment when you access a new instance (in that case you can accumulate the insert operations and apply them in batch when you new instance is firstly read).

Comment: Your last option would be a little better if you nixed the `ToList()`.. You'd have to switch to a `foreach` and track your index but at least you wouldn't load the whole collection into memory.

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 Thank you, I edited my question. It's still not very satisfying though.

Comment: It doesn't iterate the enumerable until... You actually enumerate it. Calling ToList or using another foreach. Using yield prevents that. So it's not that bad of a solution

Comment: Inserting into an immutable collection is self contradictory. Either you must refuse the insert, insert into a copy, or acknowledge that it isn't immutable. If you intend to do a clone-on-mutate, take a look at ImmutableList<T> rather than reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @AdamG an immutable list seems to have the functionality I was looking for, however it doesn't have the advantage of IEnumerables of being lazy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the solution is already nearly in the question, as comments have hinted me towards it. The following code solves my problem pretty well:

```
private static IEnumerable<T> InsertImmutable<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection, int index, T value)
{
    var i = 0;
    var inserted = false;
    foreach (var item in collection)
    {
        if (i == index)
        {
            inserted = true;
            yield return value;
        }

        yield return item;

        i++;
    }

    if (!inserted)
        yield return value;
}
```